# Using cmssdc10 in PDFLaTeX and T1 fontenc

Tags: pdftex, font-encodings

I'd like to use the `cmssdc10` font in PDFLaTeX with a T1 encoding to ensure that hyphenation still works well in German. It seems that the T1 encoding is not supported. Any suggestions? Without `T1` umlauts are displayed properly but hyphenation is poor in the document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\font\ssfb=cmssdc10 scaled 1000 

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Houston, do we have a Pröblem?
    \item {\ssfb Houston, do we have a Pröblem?}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ***Never*** use `\font` in a LaTeX document.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}  

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Houston, do we have a Pröblem?
    \item {\fontseries{sbc}\fontfamily{cmss}\selectfont Houston, do we have a Pröblem?}    
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Is there a way to define this as a font such that using it is a little easier where I need it? Or should I just use a macro? I also noticed that this makes METAFONT run and I get a font that is not as sharp as the others. Maybe I need something else, too?

Comment: You can define a command `\newcommand\ssfb{...}`. And the mefafont run + the bitmap is/should be only at the first compilation.